# How do you write an If statement function code to search if specific text is contained within a source variable in Pinescript?

Tags: pine-script

so I'm looking for a function in pinescript that'll search for certain letters on a source variable, and if it finds such letters it would do the if then output. Say if my current ticker contains BTC within the source variable syminfo.ticker then my if then statement would choose BTCUSD symbol to be my multiplier variable

Comment: Not sure what you mean by " then my if then statement would choose BTCUSD symbol to be my multiplier variable". Could you update your question to clarify please?

Comment: There is no such function that will let you loop through symbols

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. I ended up not finding it either. Although for my user needs it would be a great addition to the pinescript language.